# Automatic carousel in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I took a custom carousel and I tried to make the slides change automatically. However, whatever I try to do I can't find any mistakes. I would much appreciate some help...

I imported `bootstrap.min.css` and I followed the bootstrap-carousel instructions but still I couldn't make the carousel automatically change after some set time.

https://codepen.io/Ale3andr0s/pen/ExYPWgQ?editors=1100

HTML:

```
    <div class="slider carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide1" checked="checked" class="slider__nav active"/>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide2" class="slider__nav"/>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide3" class="slider__nav"/>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide4" class="slider__nav"/>

  <div class="slider__inner data-interval=100">

    <div class="slider__contents active"><i class="slider__image fa fa-codepen"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">codepen</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">newspaper-o</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-television"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">television</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="slider__contents"><i class="slider__image fa fa-diamond"></i>
      <h2 class="slider__caption">diamond</h2>
      <p class="slider__txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At cupiditate omnis possimus illo quos, corporis minima!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the Bootstrap carousel https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel .. it doesn't appear that you've set it up properly.

Comment: As you can see in codepen it has custom css and it works but i cant make it change automatically along with the indicators. If you can specifically locate the problem i would much appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/), you will need to add

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

to your code in order to make the carousel cycling through the slides.
If it still doesn't work, you need to change it to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 1200
    })
  });
```

Of course, you are going to also need to import both jquery and bootstrap.js, which your code doesn't do.